# TF (nan value) error in revolute joints (in RViz)

Tags: ros, rviz, joints

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi . this is my URDF file . when i load  this file in Rviz i have error :

```
[ERROR] [1481984390.816723728]: Ignoring transform for child_frame_id "link_U42_1" from authority "unknown_publisher" because of a nan value in the transform (-nan -nan -nan) (-nan -nan -nan -nan)
```

why i have this error ??!! please help me !

my URDF :

```
         <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <robot name="wrist">
     <link name="link_U20_1">
        <inertial>
          <origin  xyz="-2.77555756156289E-17 0 0"    rpy="0 0 0" />
          <mass  value="0.714108712017557" />
          <inertia  ixx="0"    ixy="0"  ixz="0"   iyy="0"   iyz="0"    izz="0" />
        </inertial>
        <visual>
      <origin  xyz="0 0 0"   rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh    filename="file:///home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws3/src/wrist/meshes/link_U20_1.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material   name="">
        <color    rgba="0.792156862745098 0.819607843137255 0.933333333333333 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin   xyz="0 0 0"    rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="file:///home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws3/src/wrist/meshes/link_U20_1.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>


 <link name="link_U42_1">
    <inertial>
      <origin  xyz="0.000247437219810132 5.31436322726009E-09 0.000888814314510933"    rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.0318119469876036" />
      <inertia   ixx="0"  ixy="0"  ixz="0"  iyy="0" iyz="0"   izz="0" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin  xyz="0 0 0"    rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh      filename="file:///home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws3/src/wrist/meshes/link_U42_1.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material    name="">
        <color    rgba="0.792156862745098 0.819607843137255 0.933333333333333 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin  xyz="0 0 0"    rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh    filename="file:///home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws3/src/wrist/meshes/link_U42_1.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
<joint   name="joint_U42_1" type="revolute">
    <origin xyz="0.0235 0.0005 -0.00700000000000001" rpy="1.5707963267949 0 1.5707963267949" />
    <parent  link="link_U20_1" />
    <child  link="link_U42_1" />
    <axis  xyz="0 0 0" />
 <limit effort="1.0" lower="-2.53" upper="2.53" velocity="1.571"/>
  </joint>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250237/tf-(nan-value)-error-in-revolute-joints-(in-rviz)/) by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 217 on 2016-12-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-17**:
This is basically a duplicate of [how change fixed joint to revolute joint in URDF ?](http://answers.ros.org/question/250230).

**Comment by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on 2016-12-17**:
i closed that question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> ...
> <joint name="joint_U42_1" type="revolute">
> ```

```
    ...
    <axis xyz="0 0 0" />
    ...
</joint>
```

> ```
> ...
> ```

An `axis` element cannot have an all-zeros `xyz` attribute.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-17**:
PS:

> ```
> <link name="link_U42_1">
> ```

up to you, but you have mixed case link, joint and filenames. Convention in ROS is to keep everything lowercase. That may make a lot of things easier, so you might want to change the names to follow that convention.

**Comment by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on 2016-12-18**:
thanks a lot . my problem is solved

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-18**:
Good to hear you got it to work.